# Opening an Existing MakeFile Project in VS2010 or VS 2008 for debugging

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I am exploring the code of an open source project..The project has its own directory structure and has several makefiles for building it on different platforms. I am working on the windows and want to pull it's source code in Visual Studio 2008 or 2010 by making visual studio project..I am able to build the project with Nmake utility of visual studio but I don't know how to debug if I don't have any .vcproj files or solution. 
So can someone has some link or provide me some guidance about how can one make a visual studio project from make file. For more information the project I am trying to build is webP api project..
http://code.google.com/speed/webp/docs/api.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anwser your embedded question rather than your headline question - you can debug the output of the NMake process simply by invoking 'devenv' and passing it the the executable as an argument.  I typically do this in the output directory of the build process so that devenv can find related DLLs and PDB files with debugging information.

My devenv (on a 32-bit VS2010 system) lives in "c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com"

Hopefully this can get you debugging!